# Метод конечных элементов. Граничные условия

Tags: c++, графика, физика

Есть программа, написана на плюсах. Решает уравнение теплопроводности методом конечных элементов. И выводит результат в gnuplot - в качестве рисунка. Tn - рандомна. В коде ниже, приведена функция отвечающая за вывод граничных условий.

```
double BoundaryFunc(double x, double y){
    double T1 = 1.5;
    double T2 = 0.5;
    double T3 = 2.5;
    double T4 = 1.0;
    if(x == 1)
        return T1 * cos(x*y);
    if(x == -1)
        return T2 * cos(x*y);
    if(y == 1)
        return T3 * cos(x+y);    
    if(y == -1)
        return T4 * cos(x-y);}
```

Необходимо изменить функцию так, чтобы на выход влиял единичный вектор внешней нормали к поверхности. Если нужно могу скинуть весь код.

Comment: "единичный вектор внешней нормали к поверхности" - к поверхности чего?

Comment: Тела (или его части).

Comment: Отлично! Где в Вашей функции поверхность "тела"? У Вас трехмерная задача?

Comment: Дело обстоит так, ведется подсчет точек исходя от граничных условий. Это всё сохраняется в матрицу. Матрица выводится в файл, а с ним работает gnuplot и выводит результат в таком виде:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5z9zd4az17tqqw/fem_new.png?dl=0

Comment: что-то Ваша картинка не соответствует коду

Comment: Возможно весь код покажет Вам полную картину происходящего.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia46rl0pyatfi7o/finite_elem.cpp?dl=0